# is AES-128-CBC already broken?

Tags: aes

I just want to know if AES-128-CBC is secure enough to use in an OPENVPN,I asked and they told me AES-128-CBC is completely broken and is considered a weak encryption. is it so?

Comment: You might want to ask at [security.se] or [cryptography.se] instead.

Comment: ok, thanks, i'll post there